How to navigate from tabbed view and back with .Net Maui Shell
In .Net MAUI I am trying to navigate from Login View to the Home View which is part of tabbed layout. After that I want to navigate to a completely separate Page which is not part of the tabbed layout, therefore I don't want to see any tabs at the top or bottom.
In the AppShell I have routes and tabs added like so:
 public AppShell()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginViewModel), typeof(LoginView));
     Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomeViewModel), typeof(HomeView));
     Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ExampleViewModel), typeof(ExampleView));

     var initialPage = new ShellContent
     {
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(LoginView))
     };

     Items.Add(initialPage);

     SetupTabs();
 }

 private void SetupTabs()
 {
     var mainTab = new Tab
     {
         Title = "Main",
         Route = nameof(HomeViewModel)
     };

     mainTab.Items.Add(new ShellContent
     {
         Title = "Page1",
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(HomeView))
     });

     mainTab.Items.Add(new ShellContent
     {
         Title = "Page2",
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PlaceholderView))
     });

     var secondTab = new Tab
     {
         Title = "Second",
     };

    secondTab.Items.Add(new ShellContent
     {
         Title = "Page1",
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PlaceholderView))
     });

     Items.Add(mainTab);
     Items.Add(secondTab);
 }

From LoginViewModel I am navigating like this:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{HomeViewModel}")
which works as expected, I am navigated to HomeView and I can see tabs at the top and bottom. From this View, I want to navigate to ExampleView like so:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{ExampleViewModel}")
But I can still see the tabs at the bottom, I believe it is the correct behavior since each tab has its stack and my new View has been pushed at the top of HomeView.
However that's not what I want to achieve, I want to navigate to a completely new page without any tabs visible and be able to navigate back if possible.
I have tried using different types of routes:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{ExampleViewModel}")
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{ExampleViewModel}")
since I thought I had to reset the current stack to remove the tabs but doing so I am getting an exception: Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack I feel like I am missing something obvious but I cannot find any info about this kind of navigation. Is this even possible using default Shell navigation and if so is it possible to navigate back to a specific view in the tabbed layout which I have navigated from?


But I can still see the tabs at the bottom, I believe it is the
correct behavior since each tab has its stack and my new View has been
pushed at the top of HomeView.
However that's not what I want to achieve, I want to navigate to a
completely new page without any tabs visible and be able to navigate
back if possible.

You can set Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false); to false in the OnAppearing() method of ExampleView to make the bottom bar invisible. See Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(BindableObject, Boolean) Method.
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
      base.OnAppearing();
      Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
}

To fix the error Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, you just need to remove the // like below:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"ExampleViewModel");

